# Pushing values inside array using foreach

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, node.js

Here's my input

```
var id = '1,2,3';
var name = 'a,b,c';
var value = 'x,y,z';
```

How can i construct a array like this

```
[
{
"id" : "1",
"name" : "a",
"value" : "x",
}
,
{
"id" : "2",
"name" : "b",
"value" : "y",
}
,
{
"id" : "3",
"name" : "c",
"value" : "z",
}
]
```

I tried like this

```
var newArray = [];
newArray.push({'id':id,'name':name,'value':value })
```

But it gives, a single array with comma seperated value.

How can i do this Pls help

**Note :** I prefer only javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate the given strings, split them and assign the values to an object in an array.

```js
var id = '1,2,3',
    name = 'a,b,c',
    value = 'x,y,z',
    keys = ['id', 'name', 'value'],
    result = [];

[id, name, value].forEach(function (a, i) {
    a.split(',').forEach(function (b, j) {
        result[j] = result[j] || {};
        result[j][keys[i]] = b;
    });
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: you are running loop 9 times . wherever others are running 3 times only

Comment: where do you get the message, which user agent or browser are you using?

Comment: actually am using nodejs, am doing like `var medicine_id = req.body.medicine_id,
                                    medicine_name = req.body.medicine_name,
                                    keys = ['medicine_id', 'medicine_name'],
                                    result = [];`

Comment: just replace id with medicine_id and name .. don't mind that

Comment: you need to change this `[id, name, value]` to `[medicine_id, medicine_name]` (without quotes for the variables).

Comment: yeah , i changed that, did some other tweaks too, and got it .. `var medicine_id = req.body.medicine_id;
                                    var medicineId = '';
                                    medicine_id.forEach(function(vals) {
                                        medicineId+=vals+',';
                                    });` as it was already array

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
var id_split = id.split(',');
var name_split = name.split(',');
var value_split = value.split(',');

var newArray = [];
for(var i = 0; i < id_split.length; i++){
   newArray.push({'id':id_split[i],'name':name_split[i],'value':value_split[i] })
}
```

This of course only works if the arrays are all the same length

Answer (score 1):

If you know the elements length beforehand

```
var allIDs= '1,2,3';
var allNames= 'a,b,c';
var allValues= 'x,y,z';
var tmpArray = [];
for(var i=0;i<3;i++)
tmpArray.push(new {id: allIDs.split(',')[i] , name: allNames.split(',')[i], value: allValues.split(',')[i] });
```

But for a more generic solution, assuming that your comma sepparated string will always match in length

```
    var allIDs= '1,2,3';
        var allNames= 'a,b,c';
        var allValues= 'x,y,z';
        var tmpArray = [];

   allIDs =  allIDs.split(',');
    allNames =allNames.split(',');
    allValues = allValues.split(',');
        for(var i=0;i<3;i++)
        tmpArray.push(new {id: allIDs[i] , name: allNames[i], value: allValues[i] });
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do as follows;

```js
var id = '1,2,3'.split(","),
  name = 'a,b,c'.split(","),
 value = 'x,y,z'.split(","),
result = id.map((e,i) => ({id: e, name: name[i], value: value[i]}));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var id = '1,2,3';
var name = 'a,b,c';
var value = 'x,y,z';

$('.resultsDiv').html(JSON.stringify(yourFun()))

function yourFun() {
  ida = id.split(',');
  namea = name.split(',');
  valuea = value.split(',');

  var returnvar = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < ida.length; i++) {
    returnvar.push({
      "id": ida[i],
      "name": namea[i],
      "value": valuea[i]
    });
  }
  return returnvar;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="resultsDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, just split the lists into arrays, then you can perform a loop or use something like map/reduce to generate the compiled array.

```js
var id = '1,2,3';
var name = 'a,b,c';
var value = 'x,y,z';

var idArray = id.split(',');
var nameArray = name.split(',');
var valueArray = value.split(',');

var newArray = idArray.map((id,i) => 
  ({ id: id, name: nameArray[i], value: valueArray[i]  })
);

console.log(newArray);
```